# unix time OR long time to date time - And - date time to unix time OR long time PHP

Tags: date, datetime, unix, time, long-integer

How to change unix time OR long time to date time

and

date time to unix time OR long time.

in PHP and html

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Long Time Convertor - Unix</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css"/>

                            <!--  *****   Time Library   *****  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >
                
                <br><br>
                
                <div>
                    <span class="label-input100">Select Date :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input type="text" name="date_picker" id="date_picker" placeholder="01/01/2000">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                
                <br><br>
                
                <div>
                    <span class="label-input100">Select Time :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input type="text" name="time_picker" id="time_picker" placeholder="00 00 AM">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                
                <br><br>---- OR ----<br><br>
                
                <div>
                    <span class="label-input100">Enter Long Date or Unix time :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input type="text" name="unix_time" id="unix_time" placeholder="1234567890" minlength="10" maxlength="10" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                
<input type="text" name="post_done" id="post_done" hidden=hidden >
                    
                <br><br><br><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
</body>
</html>
                

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#date_picker" ).datepicker({
//          showOn: "button",
//          buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
//          buttonText: "Date Picker",
//          buttonImageOnly: true,
            
            defaultDate: "01/01/2020",
//          minDate: new Date(1930, 1 - 1, 1), // it will show first date in middle of range year
//          minDate: new Date(1930, 1),
//          maxDate:'-18Y',
//          maxDate: '0',
            yearRange: '1922:2030',
//          yearRange: '1922:',
            
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        });
    </script>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
$( "#time_picker").timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 1,
//    minTime: '5',
//    maxTime: '10:00pm',
    defaultTime: '5',
    startTime: '5:00',
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
});

    </script>


<?php
error_reporting(0);

if (isset ($_POST["post_done"])) {
    
if (isset ($_POST["date_picker"])) {$date_picker = $_POST["date_picker"];}

// echo "<br>".$date_picker;
 
// Changing to mm/dd/yyyy format
if (!($date_picker == "")) {
$org_type_date = explode("/", $date_picker);
$date_picker = $org_type_date[1]."/".$org_type_date[0]."/".$org_type_date[2];
                            }

if (isset ($_POST["time_picker"])) {$time_picker = $_POST["time_picker"];}
if (isset ($_POST["unix_time"])) {$unix_time = $_POST["unix_time"];}

// changing am/pm time to 24 hrs
$time_picker_new =  date("G:i", strtotime($time_picker));

// echo "<br>".$date_picker;
// echo "<br>".$time_picker;
// echo "<br>".$time_picker_new;
// echo "<br>".$unix_time;

// Checking any selected or not
if ((($date_picker == "") && ($unix_time == ""))) {
        echo"<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo"alert('Date - OR - Long date not selected !');\n";
//      echo"(location.href='time.html');\n";
        echo"</script>";
        exit;
        }

// Checking if both selected
if ((!($date_picker == "")) && (!($unix_time == ""))) {
        echo"<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo"alert('Select any one :- Date - OR - Long date !');\n";
//      echo"(location.href='time.html');\n";
        echo"</script>";
        exit;
        }


// Processing date to unix or long time
if (!($date_picker == "")) {
    
// only date 
$date_picker_new = strtotime($date_picker);
echo "<br>"."The only Date Value at 5:00 AM is - ".$date_picker_new;
echo "<br>";
// date with time
$date_picker_new_n = strtotime($date_picker." ".$time_picker_new);
echo "<br>"."The Date Value with selected Time is - ".$date_picker_new_n;

}


// Processing unix or long time to Date
if (!($unix_time == "")) {

$unix_time_value = date("d/m/Y h:i:s A",$unix_time);
echo "<br>"."The Date is (dd/mm/yyyy) - ".$unix_time_value;
}








// Converting Date to unix timestamp
$timestamp = time();                                // or your current date
$milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);      // or your current date with seconds

// Converting unix timestamp to Date
$timestamp_to_date = gmdate("Y-m-d\ H:i:s\ ", $timestamp);
$Pre_milliseconds_to_date = $milliseconds / 1000;
$milliseconds_to_date = gmdate("Y-m-d\ H:i:s\ ", $Pre_milliseconds_to_date);

// echo "<br>".$timestamp;
// echo "<br>".$milliseconds;

// echo "<br>".$timestamp_to_date;
// echo "<br>".$milliseconds_to_date;






// *** Date difference Checker between given date and now ***
$your_date = strtotime("2010-01-31");
$datediff = $timestamp - $your_date;
// echo "<br>"."Days Difference =".round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));



//  *** Date difference Checker between two given ***
$earlier = new DateTime("2011-07-06");
$later = new DateTime("2012-07-09");

$diff = $later->diff($earlier)->format("%a");
// echo "<br>"."Days Difference =".$diff;



//  *** sstrotime to date ***
$unixtime = 1307595105;
// echo $time = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A T",$unixtime);

}
 ?>

<!--
                                **** Notes  ****            
                                ----------------
                                
10 digit figure for date time
13 digit figure with seconds


1-1-1970 5.30                0000000000000
1 day =     0000086400000
1 hr    =     0000003600000
1 min =     0000000060000
1 sec =     0000000001000

Days to 1-1-2020 = 18262
864 X 18262 X 100000 = 1577836800000

Days to 1-1-2021 = 18628
864 X 18628 X 100000 = 1609459200000

Days to 1-1-2022 = 18993
864 X 18993 X 100000 = 1640995200000

-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Long Time Convertor - Unix</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css"/>

                            <!--  *****   Time Library   *****  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >
                
                <br><br>
                
                <div>
                    <span class="label-input100">Select Date :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input type="text" name="date_picker" id="date_picker" placeholder="01/01/2000">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                
                <br><br>
                
                <div>
                    <span class="label-input100">Select Time :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input type="text" name="time_picker" id="time_picker" placeholder="00 00 AM">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                
                <br><br>---- OR ----<br><br>
                
                <div>
                    <span class="label-input100">Enter Long Date or Unix time :- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input type="text" name="unix_time" id="unix_time" placeholder="1234567890" minlength="10" maxlength="10" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                
<input type="text" name="post_done" id="post_done" hidden=hidden >
                    
                <br><br><br><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
</body>
</html>
                

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#date_picker" ).datepicker({
//          showOn: "button",
//          buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
//          buttonText: "Date Picker",
//          buttonImageOnly: true,
            
            defaultDate: "01/01/2020",
//          minDate: new Date(1930, 1 - 1, 1), // it will show first date in middle of range year
//          minDate: new Date(1930, 1),
//          maxDate:'-18Y',
//          maxDate: '0',
            yearRange: '1922:2030',
//          yearRange: '1922:',
            
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        });
    </script>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
$( "#time_picker").timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 1,
//    minTime: '5',
//    maxTime: '10:00pm',
    defaultTime: '5',
    startTime: '5:00',
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
});

    </script>


<?php
error_reporting(0);

if (isset ($_POST["post_done"])) {
    
if (isset ($_POST["date_picker"])) {$date_picker = $_POST["date_picker"];}

// echo "<br>".$date_picker;
 
// Changing to mm/dd/yyyy format
if (!($date_picker == "")) {
$org_type_date = explode("/", $date_picker);
$date_picker = $org_type_date[1]."/".$org_type_date[0]."/".$org_type_date[2];
                            }

if (isset ($_POST["time_picker"])) {$time_picker = $_POST["time_picker"];}
if (isset ($_POST["unix_time"])) {$unix_time = $_POST["unix_time"];}

// changing am/pm time to 24 hrs
$time_picker_new =  date("G:i", strtotime($time_picker));

// echo "<br>".$date_picker;
// echo "<br>".$time_picker;
// echo "<br>".$time_picker_new;
// echo "<br>".$unix_time;

// Checking any selected or not
if ((($date_picker == "") && ($unix_time == ""))) {
        echo"<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo"alert('Date - OR - Long date not selected !');\n";
//      echo"(location.href='time.html');\n";
        echo"</script>";
        exit;
        }

// Checking if both selected
if ((!($date_picker == "")) && (!($unix_time == ""))) {
        echo"<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo"alert('Select any one :- Date - OR - Long date !');\n";
//      echo"(location.href='time.html');\n";
        echo"</script>";
        exit;
        }


// Processing date to unix or long time
if (!($date_picker == "")) {
    
// only date 
$date_picker_new = strtotime($date_picker);
echo "<br>"."The only Date Value at 5:00 AM is - ".$date_picker_new;
echo "<br>";
// date with time
$date_picker_new_n = strtotime($date_picker." ".$time_picker_new);
echo "<br>"."The Date Value with selected Time is - ".$date_picker_new_n;

}


// Processing unix or long time to Date
if (!($unix_time == "")) {

$unix_time_value = date("d/m/Y h:i:s A",$unix_time);
echo "<br>"."The Date is (dd/mm/yyyy) - ".$unix_time_value;
}

}
 ?>
```